# Vue.js nested v-repeat: How to access parent $index inside child?

Tags: vue.js

I am unable to do this:

```
<ul>
    <li v-repeat="candy: candies">
        <ul>
            <li v-repeat="flavour: candy.flavours">
                {{ candy.$index }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li> 
</ul>
```

Any work around?

Answer (score 15):

UPDATE 2: `v-for` now supports specifying an alias for `$index`: http://vuejs.org/api/#v-for That should allow you to avoid naming collisions on `$index`.

UPDATE: VueJS 1.0 has deprecated `v-repeat` in favor of `v-for`. The same solution applies though.

---

Try using `$parent.$index` to access an `$index` in a parent scope.